# Custom Enchantment ID on Book That Can Be Combined In An Anvil?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command block system which checks if the user is holding a diamond pickaxe with a custom enchantment, and if so, performs some actions. I'm using a custom enchantment ID of 98 simply because unlike names, it can't be faked by a player without cheats, and because Minecraft ignores any non-standard properties rather than storing them. This part all works fine, and holding a diamond pick with enchantment 98 does what it's supposed to do.

Now, I'd like to give the player a way to actually obtain Enchantment 98. Obviously, it can't be added to the enchanting table's list (can it?), so instead, I'm making it a "treasure enchantment", obtainable in enchanted book form in loot chests. But that's become a problem. I can easily create an enchanted book with a StoredEnchantments ID of 98, but if I try to combine it with a pickaxe in an anvil, it won't let me combine it.

So how can I make an enchanted book that stores a custom enchantment ID (such as 98) but which can still be combined with tools in an anvil to apply that enchantment to it?

Comment: I've never looked into something like this myself, but are there tags for the book or enchantment that say what the enchantment can be applied to?

Comment: @MBraedley That was my first guess too, but such tag doesn't exist. Only the enchantment id and level are stored. I suppose the valid combinations are hardcoded.

Comment: @MBraedley Sadly, I couldn't find any tag like that. I assume they're all hardcoded, which is annoying, but I was hoping there was some way around it, or some way to fake it convincingly...

Comment: I think you can now make enchanted books in enchanting tables, so you might be able to do something like `/give @p book 1 0 {ench:[{id:98,lvl:1}]}` (untested)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option. Make the enchanted books have an enchant that is applicable to the tool you want, but a high level that is possible to obtain in vanilla (i.e unbreaking 7), then after it's combined, check for any tool in a players hand with that enchant, and replace it with your 98.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two ways to achieve this. Both make use of a Command Block.

The easiest  way: You can give the enchanted pickaxe to the players

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:98,lvl:1}]}
```

or if they have (hold!) a normal pickaxe you can enchant it directly

```
/enchant @p 98 1
```

The 2nd way would require a separate `/testfor` command, though. Otherwise you could even enchant a bone. 
This is testable, too...

There are probably better ways for this, but this should do the trick.

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:diamond_pickaxe"}],SelectedItemSlot:0}
```

(this would require to have a diamond pickaxe in your first item slot and also hold it.)

Comment: I know about those ways, but I was hoping to make the enchantment feel more like a real enchantment by allowing players to find the books and apply the enchantment in an anvil. At the very least, is there a way to detect the contents of an anvil for a given player so I can /give them the proper item when they combine the items in an anvil?

Comment: I doubt there is. You could detect both items in the player inventory when the player is right at the anvil's location, but I don't know of a way to detect the anvil interaction itself.

Comment: Oh, well. So in my efforts to work around this, I thought of having the player sneak-right-click with the enchanted book to apply it to the first diamond pick in their hotbar. Detecting the pick's hotbar position works fine, detecting sneaking works fine (using the stat.sneakTime)...the only thing I'm having trouble with is detecting if the player has right clicked on the book. The gamepedia Wiki says stat.useItem.enchanted_book is valid, but when I try to use it, the command block tells me it's invalid. How do I detect a right click with an enchanted book?

Comment: Detecting Right clicking has always been a pain. As for the `stat.useItem.enchanted_book` I cannot confirm this, but I believe it fires when you really use it (put in anvil and forge the enchanted item out of it). But this could also be used, if you let the player forge an enchantment and replace it with yours.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. The only problem is that since it doesn't allow the player to use an enchanted book in an anvil unless it's a real enchantment, I'd basically be preventing them from using the actual enchantment, wouldn't I?

Comment: That depends on how you do it I guess... using `/enchant` on an existing item adds the new enchantment to the existing one(s).

Comment: I guess...it'd basically be turning, say, Efficiency V into Efficiency V + Custom Enchantment, then, right? Might be the only way to go about this, then, I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: The anvil has no real inventory. A right-click on an anvil essentially just brings up a combining-items-and-books-GUI which has no need to be linked to the anvil itself whatsoever. Also, multiple players can use the same anvil at the same time with different "inventories", so any testfor WOULD HAVE to be linked to a player, if it was possible. (Of course, there is a durability to anvils, but that isn't important for this question.)

Comment: Is there still interest in this question? Because nowadays, this should be doable using `inventory_changed` advancements that call functions as a reward. If you're still interested in having it solved, I can try to work out the details.